# how to restrict user to enter only 10 characters in mobile field

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Could you please tell me how to restrict user to enter only 10 characters in mobile field.I already used 
  maxLength={10}
.but it not working .here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hellman-65dy3

```
<RFField
              component={SForm.Input}
              label="Number"
              name="number"
              type="number"
              maxLength={10}
              placeholder="Please Enter full NUmber"
              validate={required}
            />
```

[image]

Comment: My mobile number is 11 digits (12 with international prefix, which also needs a `+` sign). Also note that some people have shared numbers where you must enter special symbols after dialling to reach the right person (e.g. `#`, delays, and other digits). For some numbers, a leading `0` (or multiple) is important, so don't store these as a number, but as a string. You should use the semantic `<input type="tel">` which knows these requirements better than you do, and will show correct keyboards on mobile. Finally, remember that client-side validation is convenience; always validate on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex pattern

```
/^\d{10}$/
```

[`Demo`](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-synchronous-field-level-validation-od0w0)

Comment: currently user able to enter `alphabetically character likes abc`

Comment: @user944513 yes user won't be able to submit with value other digits, and length less than 10

Comment: is it possible make this `type="number"` instead of `text`

Comment: @user944513 yes you can change the type to number, but even if you make type="number" user will be able to add `other characters` than numbers,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the max char in the input you need to change your code like this

```
 <input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: i want user only enter `10` digit `phone number` or `mobile number`

Comment: @user944513 just update my answer. You need to use pattern in this case